# How to add a html image input to a form?

Tags: html, image, forms, asp-classic

I would like users to submit images that are hosted on websites like imgur rather than uploading them onto my server.

How would I achieve this in html?

This is what my form looks like now:

```
response.write "<form action="""" method=""post"">" &_
                 "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value=""2"">" &_
                 "Title: " &_
                 "<input type=""text"" name=""title""><br>" &_
                 "Post: " &_
                 "<textarea id=""post"" name=""post""></textarea><br>" &_
                 "<select name=""category"">"
                 do until info.eof
                    response.write "<option value=""" & info(0) & """>" & info(1) & "</option>"
                    info.movenext
                    loop 
                    response.write "</select>" &_
                 "Category <i>(pick one)</i><br>" &_
                 "<br>" &_
                 "<input type=""submit"" value="" add post   "">" &_
                 "</form>"
```

What would I need to add to make this possible?

Comment: The current code doesn’t seem to contain anything for letting the user submit an image – that would be an '<input type=file>` element. To let them submit URLs of images, you can use `<input type=url>` (which degrades to `<input type=text>` in older browsers). But this would give you just the URL, possibly syntax-checked to some extent; you would still need to write code that actually fetches an image using that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ordinary text field and ask the user to put the image URL in there. Store this as raw string in the database and display it using ordinary `<img>` tag.

Form would have this:

```
response.write "<form action="""" method=""post"">" &_
    "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value=""2"">" &_
    "Title: " &_
    "<input type=""text"" name=""title"" /><br />" &_
    "Image: " &_
    "<input type=""text"" name=""image"" /><br />" &_
    ...
```

And to display:

```
<img src="<%=rs("imageUrl")%>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use input, try this:

```
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: <left|right>;
padding-<left|right>: <width of image>px;
```

It's usually a little easier to use a button with an img inside:

Text
However the browser implementations of button for submitting are inconsistent, as well as the fact that all button values are sent when button is used - which kills the "what button clicked" detection in a multi-submit form.